# Vue.js style scoped behaviour on setAttribute class, why does it not show?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm creating a commenting function for a text editor in a Vue.js project. The commenting function will highlight a portion of text and put a comment card on the right side, similar to Google comment system in docs.

As I was working on the highlight function of the feature I realized that the `setAttribute` class only worked on a global class and not `scoped` for the component the text is displayed in. Why is this? What is the functionality behind this? I'm curious about how it works under the hood.

tl;dr `element.setAttribute('class', 'classname')` on a dynamically created element (`document.createElement('element')`) does not work if the class is in `scoped` styles, why?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p @click="highlight">
            {{ text }}
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Paper',
    data() {
        return {
            text: "Some lorem ipsum"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        highlight() {
            var selected = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
            var selectedText = selected.extractContents()
            console.log(selected)
            console.log(selectedText)
            var span = document.createElement("span")
            console.log(span)
            span.setAttribute('class', 'highlight-text')
            span.appendChild(selectedText)
            selected.insertNode(span)
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    div {
        box-shadow: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15) 0px 1px 3px 1px;
        height: 1123px;
        width: 794px;
        padding: 96px;
        margin: 100px
    }
    p {
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
</style>

<style>
    .highlight-text {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
```

Also, if you have any tips on how I can improve the code it is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue will replace the scoped css class name with a unique data attributes and set this on the element.
I.e the setAttribute tries to add a class name which actually does not exists.

Example from docs:
https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles